# How to activate bash-completion for cnpg's kubectl plugin when running on a local k3s node?

Tags: kubectl, k3s, bash-completion, cloudnative-pg

`cnpg` completion is designed to work when running like this:

```
. <( kubectl cnpg completion bash )
```

however, when running on a k3s node, the proper way to run kubectl is either:

```
k3s kubectl ...
```

or, make the `/etc/rancher/k3s/k3s.yaml` readable (or copy to the user `~/.kube/config` ), and export KUBECONFIG with the path.

When I try either, followed by one of the following options, it runs, but doesn't do anything when hitting <kbd>tab</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd>.

#### Nov 15th, 2023 Update

Following [coment from Grisha Levit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77131319/how-to-activate-bash-completion-for-cnpgs-kubectl-plugin-when-running-on-a-loca?noredirect=1#comment136565030_77131319) (thanks!)

#### An old issue, no longer relevant in v1.21.1

I noticed there is a `kubectl-cnpg` command on the path, but running the following end up with an error:

> ```
> $ . <( kubectl-cnpg completion bash )
> Error: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp [::1]:8080: connect: connection refused
> ```

#### Still relevant in v1.21.1

After loading cnpg-completion with:

```
. <( kubectl cnpg completion bash )
# or
. <( kubectl-cnpg completoin bash )
```

Only `kubectl-cnpg` <kbd>tab</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> works, (only with commands and params, not with cluster names - although I don't know if it ever worked that way).

It does not work with `kubectl cnpg` <kbd>tab</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd>

Any idea if this the extent of the completion?

Comment: Is this still present in a release with https://github.com/cloudnative-pg/cloudnative-pg/issues/1932 fixed? v1.18.5+, v1.19.3+, v1.20.1+, v1.21+

Comment: Thanks for the update @GrishaLevit . It's definitely different now. At least I have some completion now.

Answer (score 2):

The auto-completion of clusters name it's not something implemented on the plugin yet, if you like to have that feature please open a feature request on the GitHub Issue here https://github.com/cloudnative-pg/cloudnative-pg/issues

Ok the autocomplete is there and has always been there, the only thing that you need is to add the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

# Call the __complete command passing it all arguments
kubectl cnpg __complete "$@"
```

In your PATH and make it executable, that was added here https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/105867

So that's the first part of the right answer, the second part will be answered by this PR https://github.com/cloudnative-pg/cloudnative-pg/pull/3875

Hopefully that will help you